# Two different /etc/hosts depending upon the time

Tags: bash, hosts

I am trying to make a productivity suite for myself. My first goal is to block Facebook, Gmail and Stackexchange from 0900 to 1600.

As of now, I have edited my `/etc/hosts` and added 0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com and similar ones for gmail and stackexchange.

But I am a little confused about how to include the blocking duration in my script.

What I thought is having 2 different files (hosts_allow, hosts_block) and then `cp hosts_allow hosts` or `cp hosts_block hosts` depending upon time but then this would need to be put in an infinite loop or something which I'm not really sure is the best way of approaching the problem.

Any clues?

Comment: But... But StackExchange improves productivity! :(

Comment: @KristianBorupAntonsen, not when I'm trying to learn Multivariable Calculus :P

Comment: math.SE is always helpful! :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `cron`.

Say `crontab -e` *as root* — or `sudo crontab -e` if you have `sudo` set up — and put the following in the file that comes up in the text editor:

```
0  9 * * * cp /etc/hosts_worktime /etc/hosts
0 16 * * * cp /etc/hosts_playtime /etc/hosts
```

This says that on the zeroth minute of the 9th and 16th hours of every day of the month, overwrite `/etc/hosts` using the shell commands given.

You might actually want something a little more complicated:

```
0  9 * * 1-5 cp /etc/hosts_worktime /etc/hosts
0 16 * * 1-5 cp /etc/hosts_playtime /etc/hosts
```

That one change — putting `1-5` in the fifth position — says the change between work and play time happens only on Monday through Friday.

Say `man 5 crontab` to get a full explanation of what all you can do in a `crontab` file.

By the way, I changed the names of your `hosts` files above, because `hosts_allow` is too close to `hosts.allow`, used by [TCP Wrappers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcp_wrappers).

Comment: +1 for changing the filename to reduce tcpwrappers similarity. Also, I'd suggest `ln -f`, not `cp` — it's too easy to forget that any changes to `/etc/hosts` get deleted twice a day, and any software that modifies `/etc/hosts` won't know anyway. With `ln`, you'll at least have one persistent copy of the changes (whichever one is active).

Comment: I'd suggest to add an extra line to the crontab file: `@reboot H=$(date +%k) && WD=$(date +%u) && (( 9 <= H && H < 17 && WD < 6)) && ln -f /etc/hosts_worktime /etc/hosts || ln -f /etc/hosts_playtime /etc/hosts` This prevents situations where your computer is turned off during 9am or 5pm and the switch didn't happen. Now every time you turn on your laptop or pc, the accurate host file is activated.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 2 different `hosts` file, you can simply schedule a cron job to overwrite the file in `/etc` at a specific hour during the day.